# Create a tf.contrib.learn Estimator serving that takes JSON input

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am after some code that I can use to export a model from a tensorflow `Estimator` that would take JSON as an input. I could make this work with `tf.Estimator` using `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver`, but for models built in `tf.contrib.learn` I could not find any documentation. There is one example [here](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md) that creates an export with `tf.Example` serving, but `Example` is a bit tricky to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use contrib estimator, you have to look at earlier versions of the samples. Here is an example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/85c57e4da2e7edeffbb6652636e3c65b313c568f/blogs/babyweight/babyweight/trainer/model.py

Not that you are returning an input function ops.  Having said that, I would recommend you to migrate to tf.estimator if you can.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples in CloudML Engine's sample [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master), e.g.[this code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/customestimator/trainer/model.py#L267).

To wit, you create placeholders and pass them to the `ServingInputReceiver` constructor. The outermost dimension should be 'None' to handle variable sized batches.

```
def build_receiver():
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, size=[None])
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, size=[None, 128, 128, 3])
  features = {'x': x, 'y': y}
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, features)
```

Comment: I have tried that code, but doesn't work with `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` as the `estimator.export_savedmodel` expects an `InputFnOps` type for the `serving_input_fn`, not a `ServingInputReceiver`. Works OK with `tf.Estimator`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [here](https://github.com/KishoreKarunakaran/CloudML-Solutions) for a set of examples which shows how to use tensorflow estimator for Serving models in Cloud ML

**Code:**

```
def serving_fn():
receiver_tensor = {
    commons.FEATURE_COL: tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=None)
}

features = {
    key: tensor
    for key, tensor in receiver_tensor.items()
}

return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensor)
```